# Scrapy: How can I fix a URL and then have that page crawled as usual?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am using a CrawlSpider with two rules. One rule takes article links off a page and sends them off to be stored in a CSV. The other finds the "next page" link and follows it.

However, the next page link always comes back a bit jumbled up. So, I need to fix the URL (which I can do) and then have that page crawled for more links (which I don't know how to do).

From what I have read, it seems that I need to create a request, but unfortunately I don't really understand how this works. Does the request mean that the page given to it will be crawled like all the other pages? Are my CrawlSpider rules still applied to the links found on that page?

I have tried using Request(), but the link does not appear to be followed. I have checked the link and it works fine, and there are links on that page to be followed.

Here is the code:

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'ContentSpider'
    allowed_domains = ['bbc.co.uk']
    start_urls = ['http://www.bbc.co.uk/search/news/?q=credit card']

    rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//div[@class="cmWidget news"]/div[@id="news-content"]'), allow=('http\:\/\/www\.bbc\.co\.uk\/news\/.')), callback='parse_item', follow=False),
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//div[@class="pagination"]'), allow=()), callback='parse_follow'),
    )

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        CrawlSpider.__init__(self, **kwargs)
        logfile = open('testlog.log', 'w')
        log_observer = ScrapyFileLogObserver(logfile, level=logging.DEBUG)
        log_observer.start()
        log.start(loglevel=logging.DEBUG)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        item = CreditcrawlerItem()
        item['url'] = response.url
        return item

    def parse_follow(self, response):
        marker1 = response.url.find("?") + 1
        marker2 = response.url.find("page")
        fixed_url = response.url[:marker1] + response.url[marker2:] + "&" + response.url[marker1:marker2 - 1]
        fixed_url = fixed_url.replace("+"," ")
        return Request(fixed_url)
```

Thanks for any help. To sum up, the problem is that I need to follow these "next page" links, but the links are broken. I can fix the links, but I don't know how to follow them again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is the `process_value` argument to `SgmlLinkExtractor` (see [this link](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html#scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml.BaseSgmlLinkExtractor))
where you reference a function that takes `href` values from extracted links, and where you can alter their value before links are crawled by the spider.

Below, your second Rule is changed to **not** define a callback, so the built-in crawl-and-parse of `CrawlSpider` will be used to find new links. Your `parse_follow` method is changed to a regular function, that is referenced in this very `Rule`

```
def fix_url(url):
    marker1 = url.find("?") + 1
    marker2 = url.find("page")
    fixed_url = url[:marker1] + url[marker2:] + "&" + url[marker1:marker2 - 1]
    fixed_url = fixed_url.replace("+"," ")
    return fixed_url

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'ContentSpider'
    allowed_domains = ['bbc.co.uk']
    start_urls = ['http://www.bbc.co.uk/search/news/?q=credit card']

    rules = (
        Rule(
            SgmlLinkExtractor(
                restrict_xpaths=('//div[@class="cmWidget news"]/div[@id="news-content"]'),
                allow=('http\:\/\/www\.bbc\.co\.uk\/news\/.')),
            callback='parse_item',
            follow=False),
        Rule(
            SgmlLinkExtractor(
                restrict_xpaths=('//div[@class="pagination"]'),
                process_value=fix_url)),
    )

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        CrawlSpider.__init__(self, **kwargs)
        logfile = open('testlog.log', 'w')
        log_observer = ScrapyFileLogObserver(logfile, level=logging.DEBUG)
        log_observer.start()
        log.start(loglevel=logging.DEBUG)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        item = CreditcrawlerItem()
        item['url'] = response.url
        return item
```